# how to capture the clear event when clear button is pressed in notification bar in android

Tags: android

HI,
 in Android when the clear button is pressed on the notification screen i want to capture that in my application and do some stuff. please help me in how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`deleteIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) to your `Notification`.

Comment: in my code i already have contentIntent and now after adding the deleteintent , when i m pressing the clear button contentintent things are getting  executed.                                                           Intent noti=new Intent(context, MyService.class);
noti.putExtra("key1", true);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, noti, 0);
Intent stopIntent = new Intent(context, Myervice.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("Key2", true);
PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, stopIntent, 0);
now when i m pressing the clear key i m getting the key1

Comment: @jhon: Your `Intents` are not different enough, so you are getting the same `PendingIntent` back. Add some action on one of the `Intents` -- it won't change the routing (it'll still go to `MyService`), but it will give you distinct `Intents`, so you will get different `PendingIntents` for each.

Comment: i tried setting noti.setAction(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) in the contentIntent, and cheking the condition as bundle.getBoolean("key1")&& intent.getAction().equals(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) but now i m not getting the key2 and clear button press is not coming to my code at all

Comment: sorry because of typo error it was not working...now its working..thanks for suggestuon

Answer (score 0):

in my code i already have contentIntent and now after adding the deleteintent , when i m pressing the clear button contentintent things are getting executed. 
Intent noti=new Intent(context, MyService.class); 
noti.putExtra("key1", true); 
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, noti, 0); 
Intent stopIntent = new Intent(context, Myervice.class);
 notificationIntent.putExtra("Key2", true); 
PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, stopIntent, 0);
 now when i m pressing the clear key i m getting the key1 and key 2 both